# Can i test native ios app with Jmeter using Simulator

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

Can i test native ios app with Jmeter using Simulator? Also, my app requires login.
If not what is the best tool i can use for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to measure **your application performance** JMeter won't help you, it's a load testing tool which acts on a [network protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_network_protocols) level.

So if you want to collect application-side performance metrics and detect slow parts of your application it's better to use [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/411/) (comes with Xcode), see i.e. [How to find and fix slow code using Instruments](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/81/how-to-find-and-fix-slow-code-using-instruments) article for more details.

JMeter can help you to simulate hundreds or thousands of iOS application users concurrently accessing the backend or database, but this is the test **against the backend**, not against the application. If this is something you're interested in you could record your mobile application traffic using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and once done replay it with increased number of virtual users to see how your backend handles the load. Check out [Load Testing Mobile Apps Made Easy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy) article for the overall concept.

Comment: but Jmeter can also do performance testing with the load testing no? Also do i need to use the real device for the performance and load testing or simulator is fine?